# Does $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{\lceil n/2\rceil}\frac{1}{j}$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis

Does $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{\lceil n/2\rceil}\frac{1}{j}$$ exist?
To show this, consider $$0\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{\lceil n/2\rceil}\frac{1}{j}\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{j}.$$ Does $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{j}$$ equal to 0?

Comment: Hint: $$
\sum\limits_{j = 1}^n {\frac{1}{j}}  < 1 + \sum\limits_{j = 2}^n {\int_{j - 1}^j {\frac{{dx}}{x}} }  = 1 + \int_1^n {\frac{{dx}}{x}}  = \log n + 1.
$$ In fact, much more is know: $$
\sum\limits_{j = 1}^n {\frac{1}{j}}  \sim \log n + \gamma  + \frac{1}{{2n}} - \frac{1}{{12n^2 }} +  \cdots 
$$ for large $n$, where $\gamma=0.5772\ldots$ is the Euler$-$Mascheroni constant. Look up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number for other interesting stuff.

Comment: As another approach, notice $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j = 1}^n \frac{1}{j}$ is a [Cesàro Mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation) and thus converges to the same thing as $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}$ (which is, of course, $0$).

Answer (score 2):

**Cesàro Mean.** *If $a_n\to a$, then $\frac{1}{n}(a_1+\cdots+a_n)\to a$.*

So $\frac{1}{n}\to 0$ and hence $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{j}\to 0$.  Since
$$
0<\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{[n/2]}\frac{1}{j}<\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{j}
$$
then
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{[n/2]}\frac{1}{j}\to 0,
$$
as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$1+\frac12+\frac13+\frac14+\frac15+\frac16+\frac17+\cdots<1+\frac12+\frac12+\frac14+\frac14+\frac14+\frac14+\cdots$$

shows that the sum of the $2^m-1$ first terms is bounded by $m$.

With $n=2^m-1$, you can conclude.

Comment: this assumes the sequence is convergent

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi: no, the property is true for the $2^m-1$ first terms. That's enough.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your answer